# Can't Change CUPS password

Tags: printing, cups, administration

I am running CrunchBang based on Debian 6. I can't do anything printer related. It is saying I am unauthenticated. I have tried:

```
family@familydesktop:~$ sudo lppasswd -a family
Enter password:
Enter password again:
family@familydesktop:~$ sudo lppasswd -a root
Enter password:
Enter password again:
```

Yet I still can't add a printer. What do I do?

Comment: Can you provide us with the configuration file of cups? `/etc/cups/cupsd.conf`?

Comment: The lppasswd does not exist anymore on Linux distributions like Ubuntu. Is there another way to change the password? I noticed that the password was the same as for my Linux user but I don't know if it is like this for everybody.

Answer (score 0):

You're most likely not allowing certain types of access to your CUPS daemon. Take a look at the troubleshooting guide:

- http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/articles/cups/printing-cups-troubleshooting.html

#### For example

You'll need entries like this to start:

```
# /etc/cups/cupsd.conf
# Default authentication type, when authentication is required...
DefaultAuthType Basic
DefaultEncryption Never # comment this line to allow encryption

# Allow access to the server from any machine on the LAN
<Location />
  Order allow,deny
  #Allow localhost
  Allow 192.168.1.* # change to local LAN settings
</Location>
```

There are other permissions you'll potentially need to grant as well in this file.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding yourself to the lp or lpadmin group (whichever exists) or check visudo for print/CUPS related settings.